# When sending an api from flutter web, if a complex format is entered in the body

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

```
{
    "title": 
        {
            "kr":"kr_title",
            "en":"en_title",
            "jp":"jp_title",
            "ch":"ch_title"
        }
    ,
    "content": 
        {
            "kr":"kr_content",
            "en":"en_content",
            "jp":"jp_content",
            "ch":"ch_content"
        }
}
```

The body have to contain these code.
then I wrote below code in api's body.
(kr_title, en_title, etc. are received as a parameter as a String.)

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: {
          "title": 
          {
            "kr": kr_title,
            "en": en_title,
            "jp": jp_title,
            "ch": ch_title
          }
          ,
          "content": 
          {
            "kr": kr_content,
            "en": en_content,
            "jp": jp_content,
            "ch": ch_content
          }
});
```

After that I found this error

```
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'IdentityMap<String, String>'
```

I'm not sure what to do in this situation. Shouldn't such a format be included in the body?

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode that String Map and then send it.
Like This

```
var json = jsonEncode({
"title": 
    {
        "kr":"kr_title",
        "en":"en_title",
        "jp":"jp_title",
        "ch":"ch_title"
    }
,
"content": 
    {
        "kr":"kr_content",
        "en":"en_content",
        "jp":"jp_content",
        "ch":"ch_content"
    }
});


var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: json
});
```

Comment: then can i wrote this code inside body? like this?
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: json );

Comment: @sojinLee  yes , i will upadate my answer